# SharePoint 2007 - Surveys

Tags: survey

A previous administrator of my SharePoint site created a Survey for use when the site was undergoing testing. The survey itself was completed over 12 months ago and thus is now defunct.

I don't want to delete the survey and it's results completely, but is it possible to hide the survey from view so that generic users can no longer see it's existence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to:

1. go to the survey list permission settings
2. break permission inheritance
3. delete all users/groups that are not allowed to see this survey
4. add all users/groups that are still allowed to see it.
5. done.